# Do I need a transit visa at Amsterdam to stay in airport?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, indian-citizens

I have an Indian passport and would be travelling from Japan to St. Petersberg (Russia) via Amsterdam. I have 20 hours stopover for KLM flight at Amsterdam. Though I have hotel bookings outside, but it seems I do not have time to get a Schengen visa to go out of Airport. So in this case can I stay inside the terminal for 20 hours without any need of VISA? I can manage only with cabin bag and all the flights are with KLM. I have exactly same situation during return trip.

Answer (score 2):

A transit visa is not necessary, since you are not among the unlucky few listed [here](http://www.government.nl/issues/visa-for-the-netherlands-and-the-caribbean-parts-of-the-kingdom/documents-and-publications/publications/2013/11/28/nationals-of-the-following-countries-need-an-airport-transit-visa-to-change-aircraft-at-an-airport-in-a-schengen-country.html), which for the record are

- Afghanistan
- Bangladesh
- Congo (Democratic Republic)
- Eritrea
- Ethiopia
- Ghana
- Iran
- Iraq
- Nigeria
- Pakistan
- Somalia
- Sri Lanka
- Angola
- Guinea
- Guinea Bissau
- Nepal
- Sudan
- Syria
- South Sudan
- Sierra Leone